# Separating 2 bar groups in Plotly - Python

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-python

I have two groups of data I'm working with, which I'd like to show in a bar plot using plotly (example for data is shown below).

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

```
values1 = abs(np.random.normal(0.5, 0.3, 13)) # random data and names
values2 = abs(np.random.normal(0.5, 0.3, 13))
values3 = abs(np.random.standard_normal(13))
values4 = abs(np.random.standard_normal(13))
names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13'] 

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x = names,
    y = values1,
    legendgroup="group", 
    legendgrouptitle_text="method one",
    name="first"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=names,
    y=values2,
    legendgroup="group",
    name="second"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=names,
    y=values3,
    legendgroup="group2",
    legendgrouptitle_text="method two",
    name="first"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=names,
    y=values4,
    legendgroup="group2",
    name="second"
))

fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{y:.2}', textposition='inside')
fig.show()
```

This code produces the following graph:

[image: Text]

I would like to add a space between the two methods for each name (adding space between method one and method two for the two values in each value).

I tried using  `offsetgroup` but doesn't seem to work. Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only functions to adjust the spacing of bars in plotly are the spacing of bars and the type of spacing within a group. So you can force spacing by inserting a null-valued graph in between.

```
fig.update_layout(barmode='group', bargroupgap=0.2)
```

[image]

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x = names,
    y = values1,
    legendgroup="group", 
    legendgrouptitle_text="method one",
    name="first"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=names,
    y=values2,
    legendgroup="group",
    name="second"
))
# add bar plot(null data) 
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=names,
    y=np.full((1,51),np.NaN),
    showlegend=False,
))
    
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=names,
    y=values3,
    legendgroup="group2",
    legendgrouptitle_text="method two",
    name="first"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=names,
    y=values4,
    legendgroup="group2",
    name="second"
))

fig.update_layout(barmode='group')#, bargroupgap=0.2
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{y:.2}', textposition='inside')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a subplots: Check this link, and see the examples.
[Subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/)